# Fixing Stop Function on PyQt Timer

Tags: python, gpio

This code is a Python program that creates a graphical user interface (GUI) for controlling one or more timers using push buttons connected to Raspberry Pi GPIO pins. But I am having some trouble, with the stop button, when I press the stop button it latches keeping it HIGH. When releasing, I should expect the already started timers to continue counting. I have noticed, if I put `print("stopped")` in the stop function `if index == -1:` and press the button, it will print. But it will also print when released, meaning that it is doing the event twice as I understand.

The program defines three classes:

Timer - this is a timer widget that displays the elapsed time in hours, minutes, and seconds, and includes methods to start, stop, and reset the timer.

GPIOThread - this is a separate thread that monitors the state of the push buttons connected to the GPIO pins and emits signals to start, stop, or reset the timers based on button presses.

MainWindow - this is the main window of the GUI, and it contains one or more Timer widgets. The MainWindow class also creates an instance of the GPIOThread class and connects its signals to methods that start, stop, or reset the timers.

The program sets up the GPIO pins to be input pins with pull-up resistors and sets up event detection to monitor for button presses. When a button is pressed, the corresponding event is detected and a signal is emitted to start, stop, or reset the timer.

The program also sets up the GUI window with one or more Timer widgets and displays the elapsed time in hours, minutes, and seconds. When a button is pressed, the corresponding Timer widget is started, stopped, or reset, and the elapsed time is updated accordingly.

Below is the code for this program.

```
class Timer(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Timer, self).__init__(parent)
        self.time = 0
        self.timer = QTimer(self)
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.update_timer)

        self.label = QLabel('00:00:00')
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.layout.addWidget(self.label)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)

    def start(self):
        self.timer.start(1000)

    def stop(self):
        self.timer.stop()

    def reset(self):
        self.time = 0
        self.update_label()

    def update_timer(self):
        self.time += 1
        self.update_label()

    def update_label(self):
        seconds = self.time % 60
        minutes = (self.time // 60) % 60
        hours = (self.time // 3600) % 24
        self.label.setText('{:02d}:{:02d}:{:02d}'.format(hours, minutes, seconds))


class GPIOThread(QObject):
    start_timer = pyqtSignal(int)
    stop_timer = pyqtSignal(int)
    reset_timer = pyqtSignal(int)

    def __init__(self, start_pins, reset_pins, stop_pin, parent=None):
        super(GPIOThread, self).__init__(parent)
        self.start_pins = start_pins
        self.reset_pins = reset_pins
        self.stop_pin = stop_pin

        GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
        GPIO.setup(self.start_pins, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
        GPIO.setup(self.reset_pins, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
        GPIO.setup(self.stop_pin, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)

        GPIO.add_event_detect(self.stop_pin, GPIO.FALLING, callback=self.stop_timers, bouncetime=300)
        for i in range(len(start_pins)):
            GPIO.add_event_detect(self.start_pins[i], GPIO.FALLING, callback=lambda x, i=i: self.start_timer.emit(i),bouncetime=1)
        for i in range(len(reset_pins)):
            GPIO.add_event_detect(self.reset_pins[i], GPIO.RISING, callback=lambda x, i=i: self.reset_timer.emit(i),bouncetime=1)

    def stop_timers(self, channel):
        self.stop_timer.emit(-1)


class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, start_pins, reset_pins, stop_pin, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.timers = []
        for i in range(len(start_pins)):
            timer = Timer()
            self.timers.append(timer)

        self.layout = QHBoxLayout()
        for timer in self.timers:
            self.layout.addWidget(timer)

        self.setLayout(self.layout)

        self.gpio_thread = GPIOThread(start_pins, reset_pins, stop_pin)
        self.gpio_thread.start_timer.connect(self.start_timer_handler)
        self.gpio_thread.stop_timer.connect(self.stop_timer_handler)
        self.gpio_thread.reset_timer.connect(self.reset_timer_handler)

    def start_timer_handler(self, index):
        if not self.timers[index].timer.isActive():
            self.timers[index].start()
            GPIO.setup(start_pins[index], GPIO.OUT)
        #self.timers[index].start()
        #GPIO.setup(start_pins[index], GPIO.OUT)
        

    def stop_timer_handler(self, index):
        if index == -1:
            for timer in self.timers:
                timer.stop()
            else:
                self.timers[index].stop()
            
            while GPIO.input(stop_pin) == GPIO.HIGH:
                pass
            for i, timer in enumerate(self.timers):
                if started[i]:
                    timer.start()
                    GPIO.setup(start_pins[i], GPIO.OUT)

    def reset_timer_handler(self, index):
        self.timers[index].reset()
        GPIO.setup(start_pins[index], GPIO.IN,pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
        self.timers[index].stop()
        



if __name__ == '__main__':
    start_pins = [14, 15]
    reset_pins = [4, 17]
    started = [0,0]
    stop_pin = 26

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow(start_pins, reset_pins, stop_pin)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: anyone have any ideas? really struggling